# Stored Procedure Update no Common Field Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have 2 tables, `Table A` has `Order No`, `Order Line`, `receiving no`, `receiving date`, `receiving qty`.

```
Order Order Line Receiving No  Receiving Date  Receiving Qty
A      1         455555        12/01/2013       10
A      1         455556        12/01/2013       15
A      1         455557        15/01/2013       7
A      1         455558        16/01/2013       10
A      1         455559        16/01/2013       10
A      1         455560        16/01/2013       15
A      1         455561        31/01/2013       7
```

`Table B` has `Order No`, `Order Line`, `Invoice no`, `Invoice Qty`, `Invoice Date`.

```
Order Order Line Invoice no  Invoice Date   Invoice Qty  
A     1          333331      13/01/2013      32
A     1          333332      15/01/2013      10
A     1          333333      01/02/2013      32
```

How do I create a stored procedure to update the `Invoice No`, `Invoice Qty` and `Invoice Date` from `Table B` into `Table A`?

I'm very new to stored procedure, any help will be much appreciated.

Desired Output :

```
Order Order Line Receiving No  Receiving Date  Receiving Qty  Invoice No  Invoice Date    Invoice Qty
 A      1         455555        12/01/2013       10            333331         13/01/2013     10
 A      1         455556        12/01/2013       15            333331         13/01/2013     15
 A      1         455557        15/01/2013       7             333331         13/01/2013     7
 A      1         455558        16/01/2013       10            333332         15/01/2013     10
 A      1         455559        16/01/2013       10            333333         01/02/2013     10
 A      1         455560        16/01/2013       15            333333         01/02/2013     15
 A      1         455561        31/01/2013       7             333333         01/02/2013     7
```

Comment: Can you explain in plain English the logic of this update based on sample data you provided and post desired output?

Comment: Every Order have a few Order Line.

Comment: aren't Order and Order Line fields common to both tables ?

Comment: @Tac ...and what else? What the result will look like based on your sample data?

Comment: Desired Output as below :

Comment: not able to upload the desired output, may i know where can I Upload it?

Comment: Order and Order Line is common field but there is no more unique common field that able to match a range of receiving no to one invoice No.

Comment: @Tac Great. Now is there any deterministic way to correlate records in both tables? Order and Order Line don't give us much, do they?

Comment: Order and Order Line do help to narrow down matching scope cause in actual case, one order could have few order line, i jz giving one example where this order only have one order line. I was thinking that is there any way to sum the receiving qty row by row and when the sum qty match with the first invoice qty then that invoice no will be updated into Table A.

Comment: What kind? TSQL, PLSQL? What is your flavor of database

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2000

Comment: any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Write this query in your stored procedure

```
UPDATE TableA
SET ta.RecievingNo = tb.InvoiceNo,
    ta.RecievingDate = tb.InvoiceDate
    ta.RecievingQty = tb.InvoiceQty
FROM TableA ta
INNER JOIN TableB tb
   ON ta.Order = tb.Order AND ta.OrderLine=tb.OrderLine
```

Comment: I had tried the above query but all the 3 Invoice No is being repeatedly updated.